# Skagganauk abyss?

Tags: norse, egyptian, modern-influence, typhon

In Roger Zelazney's [Creatures of Light and Darkness](https://ebooks.darknetproxy.com/index.php?page=13&id=17528&db=0), he imagines the [Egyptian Typhon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhon#Set), brother of Set, as a void that often takes the form of a stallion.  He calls this entity "Skagganauk Abyss", which I always took to be a form of [Ginnungagap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginnungagap), the primordial void of Norse mythology.  This modern interpretation is resonant, so I'm wondering about its mythical roots.

- What is the possible meaning of "Skagganauk"?

Was it purely invented, or does it come from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatures_of_Light_and_Darkness): "Typhon appears as a black horse-shadow, without a horse to cast it. He contains within himself something called Skagganauk Abyss, **which resembles a black hole**, not a term in common use at the time"

So perhaps composed form Old Norse words with little regard for grammar:

- *skaði* - death, harm
- *ganga* - to go (into), to reside in
- *auka* - increase, augment; add; exceed, surpass;

as in "the abyss, going into it exceeds death", which would be a very poetic description for a black hole.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  Since there's a bounty, going to hold off on accepting, but this would make a solid accepted answer. :)